# composing Galois extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

If $k\to E$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$ and $E\to F$ is the separable closure of $E$ then is $F$ the separable closure of $k$? If $\mathrm{Gal}(F/E)$ is the absolute Galois group of $E$ and $G$ is the Galois group of $k\to E$ then what's the Galois group of $k\to F$? Is it $\mathrm{Gal}(F/E)\times G$?

Comment: Hi @Josh!  Just so you know, you can typeset your questions using dollar signs, just like in LaTeX:  "\$\mathrm{Gal}(F/E) \times G\$" gives $\mathrm{Gal}(F/E) \times G$, and so on.

Also, just to clarify:  $k$ is contained in $E$, and $E$ is contained in $F$, right?  Did you mean to say that $F$ is the separable closure of $E$?

Comment: @RaviFernando Oh right I forgot about LaTeX. Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: I think for the first question, this reduces to showing that if $k\to E$ and $E\to F$ are Galois extensions then $k\to E\to F$ is itself a Galois extension. I don't know if this is true.

Comment: That statement is not true.  For example, quadratic extensions are always Galois, at least in characteristic not 2, and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ that is not Galois over $\mathbb Q$.  See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88122/recognizing-when-a-tower-of-galois-extensions-gives-a-galois-extension.

Comment: @RaviFernando Ah ha I see that. but what if $F$ is the separable closure of $E$ and $E/k$ is a Galois extension; then is $F$ the separable closure of $k$?

Comment: Do you mean that $F$ is the separable closure of $E$???

Comment: @oxeimon I assume so, see the first comment by josh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes.  We need to prove that $F$ is a separably closed field that is separable over $k$.  But we know it's separably closed because it's assumed to be a separable closure of $E$, and we know it's separable over $k$ because a separable extension of a separable extension is separable.  (Edited: changed the word "algebraic" to "separable".)

For your second question, we do get that $\mathrm{Gal}(F/k)/\mathrm{Gal}(F/E) \cong \mathrm Gal(E/k)$ (with the quotient map given by restricting automorphisms of $F$ to automorphisms of $E$), but it doesn't need to be a direct product, or even a split extension.  Here's an example, with caveat below:

Let $k = \mathbb Q$, $E$ a cubic Galois extension, and $F = \overline{\mathbb Q}$.  Then $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ is an incredibly complicated object, and it is too optimistic to hope that it will decompose as a direct (or semidirect) product of $G = \mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb Q) \cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/E)$.  If it were, then the fixed field of $G$ would be a degree-3 subextension of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.  But the Artin-Schreier theorem tells us that the only finite-degree subextensions of algebraically closed fields have degree 2, a contradiction.

Caveat:  when studying infinite Galois extensions, it's more natural to study the Galois group not just as a group, but as a topological group, endowed with its [profinite (Krull) topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Examples).  This is because in the infinite case, the only subgroups of Galois groups that correspond to intermediate fields are the closed subgroups.  So when I talked about the fixed field of $G$ above, I really meant the fixed field of the topological closure of $G$ in $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$.  Fortunately, profinite groups are Hausdorff spaces, so finite subgroups are necessarily closed, and there's nothing to worry about here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes $F$ is the separable closure of $k$. Separable closures are themselves separably closed, so $F$ is separably closed. It's also separable over $k$ since it's Galois over $E$ and $E$ is Galois over $k$, and hence is the separable closure of $k$.

The Galois group of $F/k$ need not be a direct product. In general you have an exact sequence:

$$1\rightarrow Gal(F/E)\rightarrow Gal(F/k)\rightarrow Gal(E/k)\rightarrow 1$$

which need not be split. For example, you can let $k = \overline{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$, then its absolute Galois group is the free profinite group of countable rank. Such a group cannot be a nontrivial direct product by Proposition 8.7.7 of Ribes/Zalesskii's book *Profinite Groups*.

Comment: Do you mean it need not be a _semi_direct product? (Because that's what split usually means.)

Comment: It need not be a semi direct product or a direct product. The statement of Ribes Zalesskii only says that pro finite free groups of rank at least 2 cannot be a direct product